# Scroll up to an element from bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'd like to scroll to the button that is placed approx 300px from the bottom of the page.

[image]

So, anytime when it is pressed, the body should scroll up or down so that the button **always** gets at the bottom of the screen.

I'm really not sure how can I use common `jquery animate` for my case:

```
 $(".hamburger").click( function(event) {     
     $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(document).height() - x //need help here
                }, 400);
      });
   });
```

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the bottom position of the button (top position + button height) and subtract the viewport height from that to determine the scroll point.

```js
$('button').on('click',function() {
  var bt = $(this).offset().top,
      bh = $(this).outerHeight(),
      bb = bt + bh,
      vh = $(window).height(),
      sp = bb - vh;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: sp
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
section {
  height: 200vh;
}
footer {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
  <button>asdf</button>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>

<a href="#" class="back">Back to top</a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background: cyan;
  height: 800px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('a.back').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 700);
    return false;
});
```